# How to convert Java static two dimension double array code to C code

Tags: java, c

I want to covert following line of java code into the c code

```
static double[][] sat_data = new double[19][4];
static double[][] sat_data_notused = new double[19][4];
static double[][] sbas_data = new double[4][2];
```

so please suggest the proper way how can i declare above in C language.
and my second question is i am writing c code from the java code and their they use

```
try {

}catch {

}
```

so please tell me the alternative blocks for the this kind of function in c language

Comment: You should get some kind of C tutorial or reference manual. C doesn't have exceptions, so `try...catch` isn't easy to port. On the other hand, there might be other ways to handle errors from whatever is done inside the `try` block, in C.

Comment: but their is any alternative for the exceptions or I can just use another way for example do while or any other alternative. for this i am very confused and what about my first question

Answer (score 0):

The first three are simple:

```
static double sat_data[19][4];
static double sat_data_notused[19][4];
static double sbas_data[4][2];
```

The `try`-block is harder, but perhaps not needed since whatever it is the original code does that might throw exceptions, is very likely to report errors in C that you can handle normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch are not permittable in C.

But the firs part, have a look at this:

```
static double sat_data[19][4];
static double sat_data_notused[19][4];
static double sbas_data[4][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

About the try-catch block.

Error handling is **fundamentally** different in C than in Java, that was one of the main "selling points" of the Java language that was claimed to be an improvement over older languages like C. So there is no direct translation between the two regarding this point (as stated).

*Perhaps similar to a native English speaker with no knowledge of other languages, he can not simply take an English-Urdu dictionary and translate what he wants to say directly into Urdu word-by-word. Chances are that it will come out very wrong. He needs to know how Urdu works, grammar, levels of politeness and formality, idioms etc. etc. etc.*

**Java** throws exceptions, as you have seen in your code.

**C** normally works by returning a value from a function to indicate it's success or failure (often 0=>SUCCESS and !=0=>Error code, but **not always**). Some functions also set a global variable to some value to indicate a problem. There is no standard way that this is done, so you would need to look up the documentation for each and every function that is called in the try block, check every function's return value in your C code, and handle appropriately*.

* = Appropriately in this case may mean that you need to think through the fundamental architecture of your C application (and understand the architecture of the Java application). Depending on complexity and application, it may be as simple as writing an error message to the screen and exiting, or as complex as appending an error message to e.g. a log file and continuing along some other path of execution.